# PIN number combination that has a 3 and 8 in it.

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

So the question is, How many PINs(4 numbers from 0 to 9 with repeat) are there when 3 and 8 (in unknown positions) are in that pin and also the remaining 2 positions can be any number between 0 to 9.

My solution:

Number of combinations without the 3 and 8 in them=> 8<sup>4</sup> = 4096
then i subtract 10<sup>4</sup> from 4096 which gives 5904 combinations WITH a 3 AND 8 in them.

Is the result correct?

Comment: Look at the problem this way: you have $10^2$ combinations from the two unknown numbers and 3 possible positions for the $3,8$. Can you count them now?

Comment: Aren't there $12$ possible positions for $3$ and $8$? I think the answer is $1200$.

Comment: im sorry for some reason i dont understand why there are 3 possible positions for 3 and 8, because with 10^2 we already calculated the possibilities of 2 positions which makes the remaining number of positions to be equal to 2. so why is there 3 possible positions for 3 and 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ let $P_i$ be the set of pins that *do not* contain digit $i$.

Then to be found is: $$|P_3^{\complement}\cap P_8^{\complement}|=|(P_3\cup P_8)^{\complement}|=10^4-|P_3\cup P_8|$$

Applying the [principle of inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) we find:$$|P_3^{\complement}\cap P_8^{\complement}|=10^4-|P_3|-|P_8|+|P_3\cap P_8|=10^4-9^4-9^4+8^4=974$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

No, your result is not correct.

4096 is how many PINs there are with *neither 3 nor 8* in them, so some of your 5904 combinations will be ones like `9939` that don't satisfy your conditions.

However, the computation suggested by Markos Karamenes:

> Look at the problem this way: you have $10^2$ combinations from the two unknown numbers and 3 possible positions for the 3,8. Can you count them now?

doesn't work either, even if we correct "3 possible positions" to 12. It leads to overcounting of combinations such as `3883`.

You need to amend your method by subtracting all of the combinations that have a 3 but not an 8, or vice versa. (There are $9^4-8^4$ of each of these possibilities -- why?)

Comment: Ok i kind of understand it now, so that would mean we have 9^4 - 8^4 of unwanted combinations that i should subtract from the 5904? and that would be like 5904- 2465 = 3439 possible combinations where there are a 3 and 8 in the pin?